# toggle form hidden value by jquery click

Tags: jquery, forms, function, toggle, hidden-field

I have a form hidden input as below, where I am changing the value from "**search**" to "**search_ref**" after clicking the '***Search By Reference Code***' link.

```
<input type="hidden" id="changeme" name="task" value="search" />
```

I am only able to toggle the hidden value one way - I want the link to toggle back from "**search_ref**" to "**search**" each time it is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ref").click(function(){
        $("#changeme").val("search_ref");
    });
});
```

How should I edit the jQuery below to do this?

Please see the below jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/phil_joostrap/82jpj76p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of `#changeme`. If the value is `search` then change it to `search_ref`, else to `search` like following.

```
$("#ref").click(function () {
    var changeme = $("#changeme");

    var text = changeme.val();
    changeme.val(text == "search" ? "search_ref" : "search");
});
```